# NSURLConnection Multiple Requests

Tags: cocoa, nsurlconnection

I have an app with Tab Bar.
Each Tab starts to request some data from the Internet using NSURLConnection way once is loaded.
Everything works fine, but if I switch tab when data is still loading, then the first request is "queued" to the second one and I found my data duplicated.
How can I suspend the download of the data when the user switches tabs?

Comment: Are you performing the connection from the viewcontrollers or the tabbar controller?

Comment: From the ViewControllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct built-in support to pause an `NSURLConnection`. Instead, you need to:

1. Cancel the connection
2. Store the data received so far
3. To resume, start a new connection that requests to receive data starting from where it left off
4. Append incoming data to that already received

It's best to check that the data on the server hasn't changed in the meantime too, and that data in step 4 is the bit of file you requested.

Alternatively, it may be enough to unschedule the connection from the runloop. This should make it resumable (by rescheduling) within a small timeframe, but will fail if left too long.

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid but... I have my iVar urlConnection which is performing the download on the first tab. The user press the second tab. viewWillDisappear is going to be called, so, in there I should call [urlConnection cancel]. Is this right?

Comment: I mean: I tried NSThread, NSOperationQueue, NSURLConnection, no matter what, if I switch tab while he's downloading data, he put the bits into the second tab (duplicating the rows) and the first one remain blocked.

Comment: Well without seeing your code (which I don't really want to because there's probably rather a lot of it), can't help any further. You're going to have to figure this one out yourself in the debugger.

Comment: I think that it's not a problem of code. I'm using Apple Reachability which is giving me a lot of troubles and is also slowing down the entire app. Seems that the notifications don't start always, and that should be why when I switch Tab while downloading (or testing the network reachability) I find my data duplicated.

Comment: It is a problem that you are apparently stumbling around in the dark. Make a separate test project to get your question working.

Comment: I've done what you suggest and I've made a separate test project to see how the things for NSURLConnection go. Everything works fine and no duplicate objects. It's a matter of notification as I guessed above.

Comment: What are you using the reachability code for? It's not even mentioned in your original question.